# Braintree webhooks, GET & POST configuration

Tags: php, payment-gateway, webhooks, braintree

I am trying to use webhooks to send emails about whether subscriptions were successfully charged or not. I use bt_challenge code to successfully register the webhook on Braintree's dashboard:

```
if(isset($_GET["bt_challenge"])) {
    echo(Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($_GET["bt_challenge"]));
}
```

However, when I use the subscription information from $webhook notification:

```
if(isset($_POST["bt_signature"]) && isset($_POST["bt_payload"])) {
    $webhookNotification = Braintree_WebhookNotification::parse(
        $_POST["bt_signature"], $_POST["bt_payload"]
    );
}
```

I don't get an email sent. Furthermore, when I try to re-register the webhook from the Braintree dashboard, it won't recognize it with this second snippet of code in the file. Are both of these snippets meant to be in the same file? This part is unclear to me.

Following these two snippets, I have my phpmailer code, which is properly configured and sends a email when the script is called not via webhook. The phpmailer code is not contained within the "if" statement of either of these first two code blocks.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what the issue is. Is the webhook not parsing correctly? Are you not receiving the webhook from Braintree at all? It would be helpful to see the code that shows what you're doing with the [webhook notification object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/webhooks/parse#parsing-notifications) after you've parsed it.